# Setting and Getting Cookies

Tags: cookies

Are there any preferred ways of setting and getting cookies in EE? Whether through an add-on or a PHP snippet?

Need to set a location cookie based on user input and get the cookie within my templates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an add-on called [Cookie Plus](https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/cookie-plus) which makes setting and getting cookies via template tags very simple.